# Issue with Button Array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

So I'm programming a Java App, and I used a for loop to set the width and height of buttons.

```
for (int count = 0; count < 9; count++) {
    board[count].Height(ht);
    board[count].Width(wt);
 }
```

This code works, but I then got a wild hair to apply the dimensions like this.

```
board[0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9].Height(ht);
board[0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9].Width(wd);
```

But it only applies it to button[0].  Why is that?

Also, would there be a better method of changing the button dimensions than a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of selecting all of your buttons, your code is performing a lot of bit-and operations (`&` is Java's bit-and operator):

```
board[0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9]
```

A bit-and operation here will evaluate to zero (0 & anything is 0).  You'll need to use a `for` loop to apply your operations to all buttons.